# Как получить численное значение из input?

Tags: javascript, html

Как с помощью JS получить цифры с каждого input и с селектора чтобы в JS например я имел 3 переменные содержат в себе 50 из input = text, 5 c radio, и 60 из селектора а потом я мог додать их, передать в сменную результата, и вывести?
`

```html
<h1>простенький калькулятор</h1>

<input type="text" placeholder="Введите цифру">

+ 

<input type="radio" id="five"  name="radio">
<label for="five">
5</label>

<input type="radio" id="six"  name="radio">
<label for="six">
6</label>

<input type="radio" id="seven" name="radio">
<label for="seven">
7</label> 

+

<select id="secector">
<option>50</option>
<option>60</option>
<option>70</option>
<option>80</option>
</select>

==
```

https://codepen.io/dieie88/pen/abowZYV

Comment: Вы разобрались в своем вопросе?

Comment: Да, спасибо! Но еще розбираюсь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На "чистом" js решение будет выглядеть как то так:

```js
function getRadioValue(theRadioGroup)
{
    var elements = document.getElementsByName(theRadioGroup);
    for (var i = 0, l = elements.length; i < l; i++)
    {
        if (elements[i].checked)
        {
            return elements[i].value;
        }
    }
}

function calc()
{
  result = 
    Number(document.getElementById('input').value) +
    Number(document.getElementById('secector').value) +
    Number(getRadioValue("radio_number")) ;
  document.getElementById('result').value = result;
}
```

```html
<h1>простенький калькулятор</h1>

<input type="text" placeholder="Введите цифру" id='input'>

+ 

<input type="radio" name="radio_number" name="radio" value='5'>
<label for="five">5</label>

<input type="radio" name="radio_number" name="radio" value='6'>
<label for="six">6</label>

<input type="radio" name="radio_number" name="radio" value='7'>
<label for="seven">7</label> 

+

<select id="secector">
<option>50</option>
<option>60</option>
<option>70</option>
<option>80</option>
</select>

<input type='button' value='=' onclick='calc()' >

<input type="text" id='result' readonly>
```

Comment: значение радио можно получить так : `document.querySelector('input[type="radio"][name="radio_number"]:checked').value`

Answer (score 2):

Это достаточно легко сделать при помощи JQuery:

```js
function calc()
{
  result = 
    Number($('#input').val()) + 
    Number($('#secector').val()) + 
    Number($('input[name=radio_number]:checked').val()) ;
  $('#result').val(result)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>простенький калькулятор</h1>

<input type="text" placeholder="Введите цифру" id='input'>

+ 

<input type="radio" name="radio_number" name="radio" value='5'>
<label for="five">5</label>

<input type="radio" name="radio_number" name="radio" value='6'>
<label for="six">6</label>

<input type="radio" name="radio_number" name="radio" value='7'>
<label for="seven">7</label> 

+

<select id="secector">
<option>50</option>
<option>60</option>
<option>70</option>
<option>80</option>
</select>

<input type='button' value='=' onclick='calc()' >

<input type="text" id='result' readonly>
```

Comment: А на чистом JS?